# How do I define the values of the variables inside a C Struct?

Tags: c, struct

So I have the following:

```
struct semaphore{
int count; //or whatever value is needed
struct PCB *Sem_Queue;
};
struct semaphore Forks[5]; 
struct semaphore Doorman;
Doorman.count =4;
```

I want to set count = 4 for Doorman, but with the above code I get a syntax error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can't have statements (like `Doorman.count =4;`) in the global scope (outside of functions).

Answer (score 1):

To the whole, your syntax is correct. Please verify the following points I mentioned:

->struct PCB *Sem_Queue :- there must be a valid declaration of struct PCB somewhere.

->Doorman.count =4 :- this one and above two statements(in your code) must be declared in any function body.

Comment: I have struct PCB defined earlier in the program. I can verify it is not the problem. Your second point was what was causing my issue, thanks!